# Chrome HTML Import deprecation (Force remove for testing)

Tags: html, google-chrome, polymer

The following is shown on our website using a chrome browser:

*[Deprecation] HTML Imports is deprecated and will be removed in M73, around March 2019. Please use ES modules instead. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5144752345317376 for more details.*

According to polymer upgrading to 1.10.1 should fix this problem however it says it will still show the warning https://www.polymer-project.org/blog/2017-10-18-upcoming-changes:

*The good news is we already have a fix for this in the latest versions of Polymer 1.x and 2.x. The bad news is that we can't make the warning go away. (We're looking into a workaround to suppress this warning, which could be shipped in a subsequent version of Polymer.)*

Is it possible to force a removal of this feature by setting a chrome flag or something in order to test our site properly with the feature removed?

Comment: Testing in Firefox would give you just about the exact same result.

Comment: Seems like a test, thanks will try that.

Comment: It seems to work, but weirdly somethings still work (which shouldn't) which is confusing.

Comment: Ahhh we had a polyfiller, thanks seems to be working now :D